# Deleting PHP7.2.7 in ubuntu

Tags: php

I want to delete PHP 7.2.7 in ubuntu I used:

apt-get purge php7.2.*

I get like around 50 I guess from these message:

Note, selecting 'php7.2-sybase' instead of 'php7.2-pdo-dblib'
Package 'libapache2-mod-php7.2' is not installed, so not removed

However when I want to install magento on the server it says at readiness check:

PHP Version Check
Your PHP version is 7.2.7. The required PHP version is 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0. Hide detail

Download and install PHP from www.php.net using this PHP Documentation.

For additional assistance, contact your hosting provider.

I deleted it but there were some errors because of file permissions now I changed it. but  I think some remaining files stayed behind.

How can I get rid of them?

Comment: This question does not belong on StackOverflow. Try posting this on SuperUser

Answer (score 3):

try to use **sudo** command:

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.2.*
```